# How to add string before link text

Tags: php, regex, replace, hyperlink, icons

I want to add icon before link text. For example I have following links:

```
<a href="#" class="link-66">random text here</a>
<a href="#" class="link-67">another random text</a>
<a href="#" class="link-68">random text</a>
```

I would like to add Icon before link text:

```
<a href="#" class="link-66"><i class="icon" /> random text here</a>
<a href="#" class="link-67"><i class="icon" /> another random text</a>
<a href="#" class="link-68"><i class="icon" /> random text</a>
```

Now, How can do this in PHP?

Comment: Think you're looking for that infoarmation http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/

Comment: Did you try using a DOM parser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the end of starting tag.

```
preg_replace('#(<a [^>]*>)#', '$1<i class="icon" />', $source);
```

Comment: you mean $result = preg_replace($regexp, $source); ;-)